# Aceessing machine behind a NAT

Tags: networking

I am trying to share a WiFi connection (from host A) via Ethernet (to host B), both machines running Ubuntu.

The network sharing on host A was a simple matter of enabling in NetworkManager of a "share network" option for the wired connection. While the network sharing works properly, host B, which has a 10.xxx.xxx.xxx IP as opposed to the usual 192.168.xxx.xxx I have in my home network, cannot be pinged or connected to with ssh. I assume the issue is the firewall configuration on host A's side.

Comment: The same question as https://askubuntu.com/questions/356807/port-forwarding-through-shared-internet-connection, there is a link on how to do forwarding using ```rinetd```

Comment: Or an ``iptables``` way in https://superuser.com/a/145195/368970